# Cordova iOS deviceready never fires

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I've been developing Cordova apps for a number of years now, and often I come across the problem where the "deviceready" event simply does not fire in iOS.
(This is not the `cordova.js` file missing, which seems to be the only answer I'm finding on SO).
Currently I'm using **Cordova v6.3.1**, though I've had this same issue on many earlier versions.

Surely others face this issue - I'm going to try and solve it now and will post the answer here.

---

Sample `index.html` code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", 
               function() { alert('device ready fired!'); }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can your javascript code-block for your cordova app initialization and all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have been caused by the changes by iOS, making the push plugin I was using stop working.
I've done many things, they may have all helped, I'll list them all:

#### What seemed to solve it

1. **Remove all plugins and re-add them**

> cordova plugin ls    *(see all plugins and make a note of them)*
> cordova plugin rm *plugin-name*   *(for each one)*
> cordova plugin add *plugin-name*  *(add 'em all back in )*

#### What may have also helped

2. I updated to the latest Xcode
3. Update cordova (and cordova-ios) to the latest version

> sudo npm install -g cordova
> cordova platform update ios@latest

4. Add and remove ios platform

> cordova platform rm ios
> cordova platform add ios

Comment: I've now made a script that removes and then adds back all my plugin's - makes it a lot easier to do this fix when it is required.